# how to call jsp and servlet with parameter from javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

Here is the code where calling the javascript functions..

```
<td><input type="button" name="edit" value="Edit" onclick="editRecord(<%=rs.getString(1)%>);" ></td>

<td><input type="button" name="delete" value="Delete"  onclick="deleteRecord(<%=rs.getString(1)%>);" ></td>
```

the javascripts functions are "SSuers" is form name.

```
<script language="javascript">

function editRecord(id){

var f=document.SSusers;
f.method="POST";
f.action= 'edit.jsp?+id='+id;
f.submit();}



function deleteRecord(id){
var f=document.SSusers;
f.method="post";
f.action='./DeleteServlet?id='+id;
f.submit();}
</script>
```

please help me to FIX IT ..

Comment: what is the error you are facing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can call your jsp and servlet using

```
location.href
```

Here are the button link how to call jsp, and servlet.

```
<td><input type="button" name="edit" value="Edit" onclick="location.href='edit.jsp?id=<%=rs.getString(1)%>'; "></td>

<td><input type="button" name="delete" value="Delete" onclick="location.href='/Registrationform/DeleteServlet?id=<%=rs.getString(1)%>'; "></td>
```

No need to function call 
It works fine..

Answer (score 1):

When doing this stuff, you always have to consider how it's going to look when it arrives at the browser. Consider if your string is `"fred"`. The output of

```
<input ... onclick="editRecord(<%=rs.getString(1)%>);" >
```

...will be

```
<input ... onclick="editRecord(fred);" >
```

Note that `fred` is not in quotes, and so the JavaScript engine will think it's a variable reference.

You need to put quotes around it and properly escape the result into HTML character entities (since you're using it within an HTML attribute, `onclick`), turning `"` into `&quot;` and such, so the result is:

```
<input ... onclick="editRecord('fred');" >
```

(single quotes) or

```
<input ... onclick="editRecord(&quot;fred&quot;);" >
```

(double quotes).

There's no pre-supplied JVM function for that, but you can probably use something from Apache Commons.

Note that the HTML encoding is **only** required because you're using it in an `onclick` attribute in the HTML markup. If you were outputting it within a `script` element, you'd need to encode it differently (perhaps using the result of encoding it as JSON using any of the several Java libraries for that, since JSON is a subset of JavaScript literal syntax).